# Delete file without leaving page

Tags: php, unlink

I'm allowing my users to delete their own files from their account and folder but whenever someone clicks on the delete button url takes him to the `remove.php` and leaves `myfiles.php` and file is is removed .

I just want to delete files without leaving the page following are the codes functions which I've checked out but no succes :

**Ajax**

```
 <script>
 function loadXMLDoc()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
   // use the xmlhttp.responseText however you need.
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "remove.php?file=$actfolder&file=$file, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

---

`remove.php`

```
<?php
require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require("models/db-settings.php");

if(isset($_GET['file'])){
$filename = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username/" . ltrim($_GET['file'], '/\\');
// make sure only deleting a file in files/ directory
if (dirname(realpath($filename)) == realpath("uploads/$loggedInUser->username")) {
    unlink($filename);
}
}
?>
```

---

`myfiles.php`

```
<?php
include("db-settings.php");
include("config.php");
$actfolder = $_REQUEST['folder'];
$directory = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username/$actfolder/";
if (is_dir($directory)) {
            if ($directory_handle = opendir($directory)) {
                            while (($file =       readdir($directory_handle)) !== false) {
                                                $filet     = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/$file";
                                                $thumbimg = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/thumbs/$file";
                                               $path_info = pathinfo($filet);

                                                   if (array_key_exists('extension', $path_info)) {
                                                                 $extension = $path_info['extension'];
                                               } else {
                                                              $extension = "folder";
                                                     }

                                            switch ($extension) {
                                                            case "jpg":
                                                            case "png":
                                                            case "gif":
                                                            case "bmp":
                                                                            $filetype   = "image";
                                                                            if (file_exists($thumbimg)) { } 
                                                                            else {
                                                                                include "SmartImage.class.php";
                                                                                $img = new SmartImage($filet); 
                                                                                $img -> resize(130, 130, true); 
                                                                                $img -> saveImage("$directory"."thumbs/$file", 85); 
                                                                            }
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"$thumbimg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"view.php?folder=$actfolder&file=$file\">";
                                                                            $showthis = 1;
                                                                            break;
                                                            case "txt":
                                                            case "doc":
                                                            case "docx":
                                                            case "odt":
                                                            case "ods":
                                                            case "odp":
                                                            case "xls":
                                                            case "xlsx":
                                                            case "pdf":
                                                                            $filetype   = "text";
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"include/img/filetype/text.jpg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"view.php?folder=$actfolder&file=$file\">";
                                                                            $showthis = 1;
                                                                            break;
                                                            case "mp3":
                                                                            $filetype   = "sound";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"view.php?folder=$actfolder&file=$file\">";
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"img/music.jpg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">
                                            <div class=\"fl-au-player\">
                                            <object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"players/audio/player_mp3_maxi.swf\" width=\"25\" height=\"20\">
                                                <param name=\"movie\" value=\"players/audio/player_mp3_maxi.swf\" />
                                                <param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#ffffff\" />
                                                <param name=\"FlashVars\" value=\"mp3=$filet&amp;width=25&amp;showslider=0&amp;bgcolor1=444444&amp;bgcolor2=444444&amp;buttonovercolor=dddddd\" />
                                            </object>
                                            </div>
                                          ";
                                                                            $showthis = 1;
                                                                            break;
                                                            case "ogg":
                                                            case "wav":
                                                                            $filetype   = "sound";
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"include/img/filetype/sound.jpg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"view.php?folder=$actfolder&file=$file\">";
                                                                            $showthis = 1;
                                                                            break;
                                                            case "avi":
                                                            case "mpeg":
                                                            case "wmv":
                                                            case "mp4":
                                                            case "3gp":
                                                            case "flv":
                                                                            $filetype   = "video";
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"include/img/filetype/video.jpg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"view.php?folder=$actfolder&file=$file\">";
                                                                            $showthis = 1;
                                                                            break;
                                                            case "folder":
                                                                            $filetype   = "folder";
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"include/img/filetype/folder.jpg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"myfiles.php?folder=$actfolder$file/\">";
                                                                            if ($file == "thumbs") {
                                                                                $showthis = 0;
                                                                            }
                                                                            else {
                                                                                $showthis = 1;
                                                                            }
                                                                            break;
                                                            default:
                                                                            $filetype   = "other";
                                                                            $actionfile = "<img src=\"include/img/filetype/other.jpg\" height=\"130\" width=\"130\">";
                                                                            $actionlink = "<a href=\"view.php?folder=$actfolder&file=$file\">";

                                                                            $showthis = 1;
                                            }

                                            if (strlen($file) <= 19) {
                                                            $filestamp = "$file";
                                            } else {
                                                            $filestamp = "..." . substr("$file", -16);
                                            }

                                            if ((!is_dir($file)) & ($file != ".") & ($file != ".."))
                                                        if ($showthis){
                                                            echo "<li class=\"$filetype\">$actionlink$actionfile</a>$actionlink<p>" . $filestamp . "</p></a><a href='remove.php?file=$actfolder&file=$file' title='Delete file '$file' from the server'>Delete</a></li>";
                                                        }
                            }
                            closedir($directory_handle);
            }
}
?>
```

this code is under every file : 
`<a href='remove.php?file=$actfolder&file=$file' title='Delete file '$file' from the server'>Delete</a>`
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `AJAX` for this purpose.

Comment: i used it but i'm unabale to make it work

Comment: So use a form with post method, paste the code on the same page instead of a separate file and when after delete use `header('Location:'$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: @u_mulder Ajax is not required, understand the question :)

Comment: im not using form method to delete the files im suing `<a>` link with veriables in it. take a look at the end of question

Comment: The solutions Mr Alien and I posted should work with a normal link.

Comment: either use get or post method in php then create a link with onclick post data, which will remove the files.

Comment: Mr Alien and Rèmi 's solution worked good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of remove.php you can go back to the previous page with this code:

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

Comment: And what will `$referer` hold?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Sorry, I copied code without checking. I updated my code. Maybe your solution is better, I am not sure what is your difference.

Comment: thnxxxxxxxxxxxx it workss ;) both of you thanks guys